# Integration-by-???, i.e., is the following "trick" an example of some general integration technique?

Tags: integration

I was discussing climate change with a friend, and mentioned that given $G_{SC}=1360\mbox{watts}/m^2$ (*i.e.,* the solar constant https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant), the Earth's total insolation at the top of the atmosphere is just $I=G_{SC}\times\pi R^2$, where $R$ is (you guessed it:) the Earth's radius.

But she said that simply using $\pi R^2$ is wrong because the Earth's curvature means the integrand needs a $\cos\theta$-like factor for each infinitesimal area element, since the Sun's rays hit each area element at an angle.

Okay, that's true, but here's the "trick": Imagine a big, big movie screen placed behind (relative to the Sun) the Earth. Then the Earth will cast a $\pi R^2$ shadow on the screen, and that has to represent the total solar insolation received, *i.e.,* the final result of evaluating the definite integral, whatever the correct integrand is.

Thus, you don't have to bother setting up and solving the more complicated integral. So, is this "trick" an example of a more general integral-solving technique? Or just a one-off approach to this specific problem?

**E d i t**     Re @KurtG's comments, I perhaps didn't adequately explain my question. I'm **not** asking if "casting a shadow" is an integration technique. I'm asking that if you'd first set up the integrand with all the trigonometry necessary to account for the Earth's curvature, then would there be some well-known integration technique that algebraically simplifies the integrand in the same way? And then, in that case, is "casting a shadow" just a geometric representation of this algebraic technique?

**E d i t**     Re @Karl's suggestion, I have to admit that I never bothered (until now) setting it up, since the point was to get the answer without doing the work, by insightfully simplifying the setup. Okay, so first, for the $2D$ flat disk, the trivial integral is obviously just $G_{SC}\int_0^R2\pi rdr=G_{SC}\pi R^2$, where $2\pi r$ is the circumference of the circle at distance $r$ from the center, and then $2\pi rdr$ is the area element being integrated.

But now, for the $3D$ sphere, you'd integrate over $\theta$ rather than $r$, whereby it's harder to see how one integral might be simplified to the other. So first, we know the area of the hemisphere is $2\pi R^2$, obtained by $\int_0^{\pi/2}Rd\theta\times 2\pi R\sin\theta$, where $Rd\theta$ is just the arclength (corresponding to $dr$ in the $2D$ case), and $2\pi R\sin\theta$ is the circumference of the circle at angle $\theta$. But to correspondingly attenuate the insolation that's incident at angle $\theta$, we have to multiply $G_{SC}$ by $\cos\theta$, whereby the non-constant part of the integrand is now $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta=1/2$ (rather than the original $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta d\theta=1$), and so we wind up with $\pi R^2$, identical to the $2D$ case, as required by our original "shadow argument".

But it's not at all clear to me how that "shadow argument" might represent the geometrization of a more general algebraic integration technique. And the preceding little exercise doesn't seem to help clarify it (at least not to me). Maybe there is no such generalization, though it's also not clear to me how you'd go about proving such a negative.

Comment: Integration by neglecting what is not relevant. Viewed from the sun the earth looks like a disk with radius $R\,.$ The area of that disk is $\pi R^2\,.$ You don't even need that movie screen.

Comment: In this context you may want to get familiar with Gauss' [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement). It says in this case that the flux of sunlight "through" earth's hemisphere facing the sun is the same as the flux "through" that flat disk. This is because no new sunlight is created on the way (divergence free).

Comment: @KurtG. Does the above edit explain the question any better? (And I'm not sure what $\nabla\cdot B=0$ really has to do with anything here.)

Comment: I suggest setting up the integral to see what happens.

Comment: @Karl See second edit above. I'm seeing what happens, but am not seeing it any more clearly.

Comment: Please do not add sections of text to your question which begin with "Edit".  What you present in the question should look like a uniform bit of exposition, not something which was built up piecemeal.  If anyone cares to know the history of the question, the revision history is available to all.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Those Edits are not "sections of text [added] to your question", but replies to KurtG's and Karl's comments above. I started out by writing them as followup comments, by they became way to long for comments.

Comment: @eigengrau That's my point.  Your replies should not be added to the question as though a conversation were occurring.  They should be edited into the question in order to create a single question which does not look like an amalgam of answers to questions.  This is particularly important because comments are *ephemeral* and *temporary*, and are likely to be eventually deleted.  Someone coming to this question from outside wants to read the question, not a discourse on the history of the question.

Comment: The material you edited into the question may be important, but find a way to make part of the question, and not a series of second thoughts and addenda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection of a sphere onto a plane is a circle. What is different in this case, however, is the *physical*, not geometric, phenomenon that the intensity of the radiated light is proportional to its inverse square distance from its source. As that distance becomes large, two nearby points will have an approximately equal distance, hence a similar received light intensity, and the intensity will reduce to an approximately constant term. Therefore, as the Earth is at a great distance from the Sun, we can treat the irradiation as a function of the visible surface area alone.

In terms of calculus, we can demonstrate this by expanding $\displaystyle{\left(1/x+d\right)^{-2}}$ as a power series at $x=0$, via the binomial series, as $x^{2}\cdot\left(1-2dx+\ldots\right)$ We can then take $1/x=R$, to observe that a point at a far distance $R+d$ receives intensity $1/(R+d)^2\to1/R^2\cdot(1-2d/R)$, approximately equal to the $1/R^2$ intensity received by a point at distance $R$. Hence, intensity is approximately constant at a large distance.

To illustrate, simplify the system to a 2-dimensional cross section, with the Sun a point at the origin and the Earth a circle on the line $y$-axis. The inverse square distance (shown in orange) can be found by writing the curve as $y=a-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and using Pythagoras' theorem. We can see that it flattens as the distance increases.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Jam. Re your first paragraph, that's astronomically usually expressed by saying that the Sun's (or any body's) rays are parallel at great distances from the source. And that's what we've been assuming all along. It's just the Earth's curvature that nevertheless still attenuates those parallel rays, i.e., it's hotter at high noon when the Sun's overhead than at dawn or dusk when its rays hit you at a steep angle. (Of course, the longer path through the atmosphere also attenuates the energy, but we're just talking about the "geometrical attenuation", so to speak, here).